# command in hadoop source code for map time and reduce time

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hadoop2

we know map has two part 'chunk and combine ',and reduce has 3 part 'shuffle ,sort and reduce '.
In hadoop source code,what is the command for having each parts time,[image: I need these times in source code]

Answer (score 0):

There is an API for the JobTracker for submitting and tracking MR jobs in a network environment.
Check this for more details.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.html

```
    TaskReport[] maps = jobtracker.getMapTaskReports("job_id");
    for (TaskReport rpt : maps) {
      System.out.println(rpt.getStartTime());  
      System.out.println(rpt.getFinishTime());
    }
    TaskReport[] reduces = jobtracker.getReduceTaskReports("job_id");
    for (TaskReport rpt : reduces) {

      System.out.println(rpt.getStartTime());
System.out.println(rpt.getFinishTime());
    }
```

or If you are using Hadoop 2.x, ResourceManager REST API's have been provided.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/HistoryServerRest.html
[image]

Comment: in hadoop v2 we dont have jobtracker,also I need the time of each 5 parts.